# WHat does Cross sign indicates on a file in Git for windows

Tags: windows, git, git-clone, git-stash, git-status

I am using Git client for windows.

I recently pulled a repository and did some modifications and deleted some files (Not shift delete).

When I undo-ed the delete I see the attached cross mark on the file/What does that mean?

If something is wrong , how can I revert back to the original situtaion.

[image]

Comment: I'm a Mac user, but I'd expect it means the deletes are still staged. Do a 'git status' and see if they're listed. If they are and you don't want them to be run a git stash

Comment: @TomDunning How can I revert back to the orginal situation?-"Files not appearing with cross over them"

Comment: show me what your `git status` shows and I can be sure, but if you've undone the delete you probably just want to do `git add -A` then `git commit -am "my revert commit"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deleted the file.

In order to revert (since i don't know which client you are using)
it open the git bash and follow this steps:

I assume you are using tortoise git:

[image]

```
# Open git bash in the desired folder
git status

# now you should see your desired file in the list marked as deleted
git checkout <file name>
```

Here is a screenshot for you

[image]

Comment: It seems I dont have git bash.I have Tortoise git (GUI) and I find no option to checkout.Can I do "fetch" or shall I install git bash? Thanks for you feedback.